# Accessing H2 PG Server using TCP

Tags: java, database, h2

I've configured H2 In-Memory Database using the following parameters:
java -server -cp "h2-1.3.168.jar" org.h2.tools.Server -pg -tcp

I can access the pg server using ODBC and create tables and data with my windows application.
I can access the tcp server using Squirrel SQL client and create tables and data.

But: I can not access data created in the pg server from Squirrel connected to tpc server. But that's exactly the thing I'd like to do.

So, is this possible? How?
I did not found any hints in the documentation.

Or, am I trying something which is not provided?

Regards, Stefan

Comment: I start Squirrel using this URL: 
jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

My OBDC Configuration is using Postgres SQL Driver with the following parameters:
Server: 127.0.0.1
Port 5435 (default)
Database: mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF;

Comment: URL above was wrong, it's  jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1/mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

Problem solved.